# What is the "invert" attribute on a html tag for?

Tags: html

Just curious. I just noticed this in YouTube html source code:

```
<!doctype html><html  invert style=...
```

What is the invert attribute for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such [attribute in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fullindex.html#attributes-table).

It is presumably a non-standard extension used by YouTube's JavaScript. (HTML provides [`data-*` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-data) for that kind of thing, so it is unclear why YouTube isn't using one there).